# web videos don't play in any browser, debian

Tags: debian, browser, web

I'm so stumped by this problem I'm having. When I boot up my computer (thinkpad T470p, running Debian 4.19.12-1) everything is fine, but after some time, youtube videos stop playing and give a message :

> "if playback doesn't begin shortly, restart your device"

and certain other web videos (e.g. https://i.stack.imgur.com/W60g1.jpg ) won't play either; instead it shows exactly two frames and then freezes. In facebook videos, part of the video will load, and if I click to a later part of the video it will continue loading a bit more, and will show the corresponding freeze frame, but it will never play. This is true in all browsers - firefox, chrome, and torbrowser - with or without any addons or in safe mode. So it must be something system-wide, but I have no idea how to debug that or what to search for. I don't see anything in dmesg but don't know where else to look. I have no problems playing non-web videos. Any advice?

Edit: I have a hybrid graphics card and have blacklisted nouveau in order to only use the intel drivers, but this didn't fix the problem. Restarting lightdm *does* fix the problem, but I don't know why or how to prevent it based on that.

Comment: `4.19.12-1` is the kernel image for `Debian Buster` which is an upstream release and not supported at the moment. The only thing that you can do is file a bug report for it so that it might be fixed when it's supported.

Comment: Are you using the opensource graphics drivers or the proprietary ones?

Comment: Play videos with external program, e.g. mpv.

Comment: Igor, is there a generic way to play web videos in an external player? Occasionally I can right click and save but not usually.

Comment: Michael, thanks for pointing me in a searchable direction - I am using nouveau drivers (but have a hybrid graphics card) so I tried to use nvidia instead, that didn't work so I simply blacklisted nouveau entirely, still got the problem using the intel drivers for the non-discrete card. I did discover now though that if I restart lightdm, it fixes the problem. but I don't know how to prevent it in the first place or what that even means...